# Prevent Plug.ErrorHandler from re-raising error after callback

Tags: json, elixir, plug

### Background

I have a simple Plug router with a PUT endpoint that receives a JSON body. To parse it I am using [Plug.Parsers](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html).

### Problem

The `Plug.Parsers` plug works fine and puts the json inside `conn.body_params`. However, if the JSON I am receiving is malformated, my application explodes with errors. To prevent this I am using [Plug.ErrorHandler](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.ErrorHandler.html) but since it re-raises the error after, the app still explodes.

### Code

This is my router.

```
defmodule Api do
  use Plug.{Router, ErrorHandler}

  alias Api.Controllers.{Products, NotFound}

  plug Plug.Logger
  plug :match
  plug Plug.Parsers,
    parsers: [:urlencoded, :json],
    pass:  ["text/*"],
    json_decoder: Jason
  plug :dispatch

  put "/products",    do: Products.process(conn)

  match _, do: NotFound.process(conn)

  def handle_errors(conn, %{kind: _kind, reason: _reason, stack: _stack}) do
    send_resp(conn, conn.status, "Something went wrong")
  end
end
```

It should be noted that in reality `Products.process` is not (or should not be) called because `Plug.Parsers` raises before.

And this is my test:

```
    test "returns 400 when the request is not a valid JSON" do
      # Arrange
      body_params = "[{\"id\": 1}"  # this is not valid JSON

      conn =
        :put
        |> conn("/products", body_params)
        |> put_req_header("accept", "application/json")
        |> put_req_header("content-type", "application/json")

      # Act
      conn = Api.call(conn, Api.init([]))

      # Assert
      assert conn.state == :sent
      assert conn.status == 400
      assert conn.resp_body == "Invalid JSON in body request"
    end
```

### Error

As you can probably guess, I am expecting the request to return 400 and a nice error message. Instead I get this:

> test PUT /cars returns 400 when the request has invalid JSON body
> (ApiTest) test/api_test.exs:157
> ** (Plug.Parsers.ParseError) malformed request, a Jason.DecodeError exception was raised with message “unexpected end of input at position
> 10” code: conn = Api.call(conn, @opts) stacktrace: (plug 1.10.4)
> lib/plug/parsers/json.ex:88: Plug.Parsers.JSON.decode/2 (plug 1.10.4)
> lib/plug/parsers.ex:313: Plug.Parsers.reduce/8 (api 0.1.0)
> lib/api.ex:1: Api.plug_builder_call/2 (api 0.1.0)
> lib/plug/error_handler.ex:65: Api.call/2 test/api_test.exs:168: (test)

I am rather dumbfounded.

### Failed Fix

To avoid this I tried modifying the `handle_errors` function to the following, but it still failed:

```
def handle_errors(conn, %{kind: _kind, reason: _reason, stack: _stack}) do
    send_resp(conn, conn.status, "Something went wrong")
    {:error, :something_went_wrong}
end
```

Nothing I do seems to have control over the error.

### Question

How can I prevent this error from re-raising and simply return the nice error message I have in my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should prevent the error from re-raising. I think the problem is that your tests are not expecting the error.

You could [catch the error](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Assertions.html#catch_error/1):

```rb
assert %Plug.Parsers.ParseError{} =
         catch_error(Api.call(conn, Api.init([])))
```

Or you could avoid the problem by using an HTTP client to test your endpoint, rather than excercise your plug directly. For example, using Tesla:

```rb
assert %{status: 400, body: "Invalid JSON in body request"} =
    Tesla.put!(@base_url <> "/products", "")
```